# How to get IPA file of any iOS application

Tags: ios, automation

I am looking for getting IPA file  of an ios application for which I do not have either project code , nor development id or bundle Id.

The application is available in app store. I have installed it into iOS mobile ....but for automation I am looking for it's IPA file.

Comment: Why do you need the IPA file for automation?

Comment: Open XCode, attach a device with the app installed. Press shift+command+2 then select your device. You might see the app under Installed apps.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear whether you're trying to download the .ipa from the App Store, recover it from a device, or generate it somehow. These files are basically zipped archives — once the app is installed, the .ipa probably doesn't exist on the device. And it seems unlikely that Apple would make it easy to download it from the store yourself.

If your goal is to set up a large number of devices, you should take a look at [Apple Configurator](https://support.apple.com/apple-configurator) and the [Managed Distribution](https://help.apple.com/configurator/mac/2.8/#/cadbf9c811) capability that it provides. Together with the "volume purchase plan," you can assign apps to the devices you're managing.